# Unable to mount a volume to a docker container during jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, volume, mounted-volumes

I have a jenkins pipeline to checkout, build and deploy a react project.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine'
            args '-v /home/nginx/console:/home/'
            args '-p 3000:3000' 
        }
    }
        environment {
        CI = 'true' 
    }

    stages {
        stage('Install') { 
            steps {
                sh 'touch /tmp/azeiodfsihqznlkdsqjfn'
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm test' 
            }
        }

        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm run build' 
            }
        }



        stage('Deploy') {

            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                sh '$(pwd)'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to mount the folder `/home` of my container with the directory `/home/nginx/console` on my host. After the build, inside the container, I will move the `dist/*` content to /home in order to have it inside `/home/nginx/console`

But it seems that the volume is not mounted. When I create a file inside /home, I have nothing in my host.

EDIT : in my console log I have :

```
Checking out Revision 3471c656f032692288de13f357c4b8ba54b16ca4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 3471c656f032692288de13f357c4b8ba54b16ca4
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk c5930fc469fd066720df45cdf466788957cdb0bc # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:6-alpine
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container 1ce58d845edf831599312c3d016c418a720891ea17c7bacd8327c48f9c44e9f6
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -p 3000:3000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-developer-console --volumes-from 1ce58d845edf831599312c3d016c418a720891ea17c7bacd8327c48f9c44e9f6 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** node:6-alpine cat
$ docker top 2fe2bdef3f475373cf85dfd452b6bbda21bc02dc308458ffff061b0ae9e963ec -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Install)
[Pipeline] sh
+ touch /home/azeiodfsihqznlkdsqjfn
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm install
```

Please, do you know how could I correct it ?

Comment: I think Docker has not permission to read and write to your home folder. check docker logs <NAME> to ee what happened

Comment: If you check the console output of the job in Pipeline, it will show the exact `docker` command constructed from your usage and relevant output to stdout and stderr. Could you check on that for assistance with debugging?

Comment: @LinPy, I set the right 777 on this folder and docker was installed with root user. In docker logs containerId, I have files created inside the container but not in the host

Comment: @MattSchuchard I update the description

Comment: Your second `args` is overriding the first. Combine them with `args '-v /home/nginx/console:/home/ -p 3000:3000'`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks. you are right. It works perfectly. Thank very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the trailing slash from the `/home/` path on the mount as currently I'd expect your mount `-v /home/nginx/console:/home/` to create the mount `/home/console`.

So either write your files to `/home/console` inside the container, or update your mount statement to read:

`args '-v /home/nginx/console:/home'`

Comment: It doesnt work. I remove the / in the front of home. Run my pipeline, create a file using touch in /home but I got nothing in /home/nginx/console.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t need to do anything here (and in particular you should be able to remove the `args '-v ...'` line).  Jenkins will on its own mount the workspace directory into the Docker container on the same path as on the host.

By the time you get up to the `Deploy` stage the built content is in the Jenkins workspace directory, both on your host and inside the container.  If you’re running Jenkins on your production system (consider moving it!) and the “deployment” action really is just copying to a different host directory, you can declare an alternate [`agent`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) for that one step.  I would try making the pipeline look like

```
stage('Deploy') {
  agent { any }
  steps {
    ...
  }
}
```

(Practically I’d probably invert this and run only the `npm` steps inside Docker, defaulting to run not in Docker.)

Comment: You are right when you say that the files are created on the host, in my jenkins directory. That's true. The problem is that, when I run the command cp, move or another, these commands are executed inside the container and not on the host.                       I created a freestyle job to deploy, but when I ask to cp from workspace to /home/nginx/console, I got error saying that the folder doesn't exist. Because he is looking inside the container.

Comment: That’s what the alternate `agent` was going for — to try to get out of the Docker container — but it’s tricky for me to actually try it.

Comment: I finally mounted the /home of jenkins to my /home/nginx/console during the run of jenkins. And at the end of my pipeline, I run an freestyle job that copy the files to /home...And I can see my files, finally in the /home/nginx/console. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Matt in comment, the solution is to have just one command

Your second args is overriding the first. Combine them with args

```
'-v /home/nginx/console:/home/ -p 3000:3000'
```